# How to resolve System.Runtime version difference

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

In my .net Framework 4.7.2 mvc web application I have the System.Runtime 4.3.0 nuget package referenced but when I run it I get the following error.

```
The type 'System.Object' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=4.0.20.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.
```

If I try to downgrade the current 4.3.0 reference to 4.0.20.0 that doesn't work because other references rely on that 4.3.0 version.  I thought that anything needing an earlier reference would work with a later one if I specified it in the web.config file, but that isn't working either.

```
<dependentAssembly>
   <assemblyIdentity name="System.Runtime" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
   <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.1.2.0" newVersion="4.1.2.0" />
</dependentAssembly>
```

How do I fix this?